# how to obtain a dodged geom_bar (ggplot2) from different columns of a df

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

Dataframe `df` is shown:

```
     ID               gene1                   gene2
    4602              TET2                    TET2
    4602              TP53                    TP53
    4602              TET2                    TET2
    5095             ASXL1                   ASXL1
    5095            DNMT3A                  DNMT3A
    5095              NPM1                    <NA>
```

I have been trying to obtain a *matching* barplot displaying a count (bars) for both the column `gene1` and `gene2`. the `gene1` method is the standard, while gene2 is another mutation detector that should be compared to `gene1`. As you see, in sample `5095` only 2 mutations were detected, while the 3rd was not reproduced.

**How do i make a barplot with two bars for each `ID` showing the count in `gene1` and `gene2`?**

here dput()

```
structure(list(ID = c(4602, 4602, 4602, 5095, 5095, 5095, 5095, 
4649, 4649, 4649, 5069, 5069, 5069, 5146, 5132, 5132, 5132, 5132, 
5132, 5132, 4297, 4297, 4297, 4297, 4297, 4345, 4345, 4345, 4345, 
4345, 4356, 4356, 4356, 4356, 4385, 4385, 4385, 4385, 4385, 4385, 
4437, 4437, 4437, 4437, 4437, 4437, 4442, 4442, 4442, 4442, 4442, 
4479, 4479, 4479, 4479, 4479, 4479, 4479, 4479, 4479, 4479, 4479, 
4479, 4479, 4479, 4479, 4487, 4487, 4487, 4487, 4487, 4487, 4537, 
4537, 4537, 4537, 4537, 4537, 4621, 4621, 4621, 4621, 4621, 4621, 
4621, 4624, 4624, 4624, 4624, 4624, 4665, 4736, 4736, 4736, 4736, 
4736, 4895, 4895, 4895, 4895, 4895, 4903, 4903, 4903, 4903, 4691, 
4691, 4691, 4691, 4261, 4261, 4261, 4261, 4394, 4394, 4394, 4394, 
4424, 4424, 4424, 4424, 4943, 4943, 4943, 5073, 5169, 5169), 
    gene1 = c("TET2", "TP53", "TET2", "ASXL1", "DNMT3A", "NPM1", 
    "PTPN11", "TP53", "TP53", "TET2", "DNMT3A", "TET2", "TET2", 
    "negative", "JAK2", "ASXL1", "BRAF", "CBL", "TET2", "TET2", 
    "DNMT3A", "IDH1", "NPM1", "CREBBP", "FLT3", "DNMT3A", "FLT3", 
    "NPM1", "BCOR", "KIT", "DNMT3A", "IDH1", "NRAS", "BCOR", 
    "KRAS", "NPM1", "PTPN11", "ETV6", "PHF6", "TET2", "DNMT3A", 
    "KRAS", "NPM1", "WT1", "TET2", "WT1", "DNMT3A", "FLT3", "NPM1", 
    "NRAS", "WT1", "DNMT3A", "IDH2", "NPM1", "SRSF2", "ATRX", 
    "CUX1", "CUX1", "FLT3", "GNAS", "PHF6", "PIGA", "PIGA", "PRPF40B", 
    "PTPN11", "TET2", "IDH1", "IDH2", "RUNX1", "U2AF1", "TET2", 
    "TP53", "DNMT3A", "IDH2", "ATRX", "GATA2", "STAG2", "TP53", 
    "IDH2", "SRSF2", "ASXL1", "GATA1", "KDM6A", "STAG2", "TP53", 
    "IDH2", "JAK2", "SRSF2", "ASXL1", "RIT1", "KRAS", "NPM1", 
    "NRAS", "NRAS", "BCOR", "MYD88", "FLT3", "NPM1", "NRAS", 
    "TET2", "TET2", "DNMT3A", "IDH1", "NPM1", "CREBBP", "DNMT3A", 
    "IDH1", "IDH2", "NPM1", "FLT3", "FLT3", "GATA2", "SH2B3", 
    "FLT3", "NPM1", "KDM6A", "SMC1A", "IDH2", "SRSF2", "ASXL2", 
    "RUNX1", "IDH2", "JAK2", "NPM1", "JAK2", "SRSF2", "STAG2"
    ), gene2 = c("TET2", "TP53", "TET2", "ASXL1", "DNMT3A", NA, 
    "PTPN11", "TP53", "TP53", "TET2", "DNMT3A", NA, "TET2", "PTEN", 
    NA, NA, "BRAF", "CBL", "TET2", "TET2", "JAK2", "SRSF2", NA, 
    "DNMT3A", "IDH1", "NPM1", NA, "FLT3", "DNMT3A", "FLT3", "NPM1", 
    NA, NA, "DNMT3A", "IDH1", "NRAS", "BCOR", "KRAS", "NPM1", 
    "PTPN11", "ETV6", "PHF6", "TET2", "DNMT3A", "KRAS", "NPM1", 
    NA, "TET2", NA, "DNMT3A", "FLT3", "NPM1", "NRAS", NA, NA, 
    "IDH2", "NPM1", "SRSF2", NA, "CALR", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, "IDH1", "IDH2", "RUNX1", "U2AF1", "TET2", 
    NA, "DNMT3A", "IDH2", NA, NA, NA, NA, "IDH2", "SRSF2", "ASXL1", 
    NA, NA, "KMT2D", "TP53", "IDH2", "JAK2", "SRSF2", "ASXL1", 
    NA, "KRAS", "NPM1", "NRAS", "NRAS", NA, NA, "FLT3", "NPM1", 
    "NRAS", "TET2", "TET2", "DNMT3A", "IDH1", "NPM1", "CREBBP", 
    "DNMT3A", "IDH1", "IDH2", "NPM1", "FLT3", "FLT3", NA, NA, 
    "FLT3", "NPM1", NA, "SMC1A", "IDH2", "SRSF2", NA, "RUNX1", 
    "IDH2", "JAK2", "NPM1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-127L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more:

```
df %>%  
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  add_count(gene1, gene2) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = contains("gene")
  ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(factor(name), n, fill=value, group=value, label=value)) + 
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(.~ID, scales = "free_y") +
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  theme_classic()+
  xlab("") +
  guides(fill=FALSE)
```

[image]

Last try, now it should work. Now we count before pivoting:

```
df %>%  
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  add_count(gene1, gene2) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = contains("gene")
  ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(factor(name), n, fill=value, group=value)) + 
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(.~ID, scales = "free_y") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow=2))
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to be the way, but i need the IDs on the x-axis

Comment: Please see my update. We can tweak this, depending of what your end result should look like!

Comment: I checked your last update, but I'd need two adjacent bars for ID: 4602, one with the output from gene1 and one from gene2. Though what you have done kinda conveys the same information but is much harder to interpret

Comment: We are basically there, your last update is what I am looking for. The only thing is that when applied to my whole df (127 rows, 3 columns) it looks correct for most IDs but in some cases it gives a wild number of counts. I will edit the question adding dput() so that you can understand what I mean. Check the barplot of ID 4479.

Comment: Please see my update!

Comment: Thank you a lot for the effort but it seems to me that there is an error when pivot_longer and add_count are used. The counts displayed are not correct if you compare them to those that you see in the original dataframe. That's the only issue that is still not resolved

Comment: The problem was to count after pivoting. We have to count before pivoting!

Comment: Great! Thank you so much

Comment: Perfect thank you. Last question if you don't mind, do you think it is possible to stack the name of the gene on each colored rectangle making up the bar?

Comment: I think you should accept this answer. Then open a new question with referring to this. like  My question releates to this <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69608888/how-to-obtain-a-dodged-geom-bar-ggplot2-from-different-columns-of-a-df/69608977?noredirect=1#comment123083031_69608977> How to label stacked barcharts ....

Comment: Please see my update!